# Consistent QISkit error: "All devices are currently unavailable"

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I am attempting to run the following on a remote backend through QISkit:

> ```
> try:
>     import math
>     from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister
>     from qiskit import execute, IBMQ, Aer
>     from qiskit.backends.ibmq import least_busy
>
>     q = QuantumRegister(1, 'q')
>     c1 = ClassicalRegister(1, 'c1')
>     c2 = ClassicalRegister(1, 'c2')
>     qc1 = QuantumCircuit(q, c1)
>     qc2 = QuantumCircuit(q, c2)
>     qc1.ry(math.pi*0.25, q[0])
>     qc2.ry(math.pi*0.25, q[0])
>
>     qc1.measure(q, c1)
>     qc2.measure(q, c2)
>
>     backend_sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
>
>     job_sim1 = execute(qc1, backend_sim)
>     result_sim1 = job_sim1.result()
>
>     job_sim2 = execute(qc2, backend_sim)
>     result_sim2 = job_sim2.result()
>
>     print("simulation one: ", result_sim1)
>     print(result_sim1.get_counts(qc1))
>     print("simulation two: ", result_sim2)
>     print(result_sim2.get_counts(qc2))
>
>     ibmq_backends = IBMQ.backends()
>
>     print("Remote backends: ", ibmq_backends)
>     try:
>         least_busy_device = least_busy(IBMQ.backends(simulator=False))
>         print("Running on current least busy device: ", least_busy_device)
>
>         job_exp = execute(qc, least_busy_device, shots=1024, max_credits=10)
>         result_exp = job_exp.result()
>
>         print("experiment: ", result_exp)
>         print(result_exp.get_counts(qc))
>     except:
>         print("all devices are unavailable.")
> except QiskitError as ex:
>     print('an error occurred. Error = {}'.format(ex))
> ```

After the local qasm simulator runs, I receive:

> ```
> Remote backends: []
> All devices are currently unavailable
> ```

However, if I run the "hello_quantum.py" example given through IBMQ, I am able to access multiple backends and use the ibm_16_melbourne computer. Interestingly, there seems to be an error in this program specifically.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

To use the remote backends, you need to sign into the IBM Q Experience. This is done with

```
IBMQ.load_accounts()
```

(after IBMQ has been imported, of course). Since `IBMQ.backends()` returns the list of backends that your account allows you to use, it will return an empty list when you are not signed in.

An additional note: If you update to the most recent Qiskit version (as of 2019-02-20) you'll need to use `from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy` to import `least_busy`.

Comment: I realize I had forgotten to load my account, thank you very much! I am able to now print a list of remote backends and select the least busy device. However, I am still unable to run the simulation through this device for some reason. I receive the same error: "All devices are currently unavailable". I have even tried to enable my account again through "qiskit.IBMQ.enable_account()" but I receive a warning that my credentials are already in use. Any more suggestions?

Comment: There's a full list of things you can try here
https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5532/cannot-load-account-with-qiskit
Other than that, I'm not sure. Is your account able to run jobs on the Q Experience web interface?

Comment: I was able to get it running now, thank you very much!