# Cannot load account with Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit

I just got started with Qiskit. When I tried to save my account with the API token from IBMQ website, I got the error: `warnings.warn('Credentials already present. Set overwrite=True to overwrite.')`. Then I set `overwrite = True` but the warning was still raised and I cannot save the account and connect to the server.

Comment: Welcome to quantum computing SE! I hope you don't mind that I've made slight adjustments to the formatting of the question. If you've got any questions about the site, feel free to take the [tour], have a look around [meta] and join us in [chat]

Answer (score 1):

Here's some general info, which will hopefully help you find and fix your issue.

You can try using

```
print(IBMQ.stored_accounts())
```

to see what accounts you have stored on disk, and maybe see why they aren't working.

To simultaneously sign into all accounts on this list, use

```
IBMQ.load_accounts()
```

To only sign into the first, use

```
token = IBMQ.stored_accounts()[0]['token']
url = IBMQ.stored_accounts()[0]['url']
IBMQ.enable_account(token,url)
```

To only sign into the second, replace the `[0]` above with `[1]`, and so on.

To see which accounts you are currently logged into, use

```
print(IBMQ.active_accounts())
```

If you want to start afresh by removing all accounts from disk, use

```
IBMQ.delete_accounts()
```

Adding new accounts is then done with

```
IBMQ.save_account(token,url)
```

Where token is a string that represents your API token, and

```
url = 'https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/api'
```

for those using the public level access.

Answer (score 1):

James Thanks... your suggestion worked, with only exception that now, over the period, commands are updated, like IBMQ.delete_accounts() changed to IBMQ.delete.account() and so on...

See ***Account Management*** section in the below link for version "<0.3/v1" vs ">=0.3/v2" credentials:

https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/#updating-your-ibm-q-experience-credentials